# How big does hail need to be to damage auto body panels?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

I am trying to determine under what conditions falling hail will dent automobile panels. For example, is it determined by the size of the hail, the speed of impact, force, energy, etc.?

I know there are many variables that must be taken into account to get to an answer, such as the material strength, angle of impact, thickness of material, alloy compound, age of car, etc. but surely with the global automobile market worth over $9 trillion there must be some useful rule or heuristic for designing these panels to resist hail damage.

I have read [The Numerical Prediction of Panel Dent Resistance Incorporating Panel Forming Strains](http://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/s4/f2/dsk3/OWTU/TC-OWTU-22.pdf) but it does not take hail as a main force into account. I am not an engineer so I don't know how to get a figure from this paper.

Comment: Size doesn't matter... Momentum transfer does!